# Multiple Processes on Microchip PIC32 Ethernet Starter Kit

Tags: process, embedded, pic

I have just received a Microchip PIC32 Ethernet Starter Kit.

I have zero prior experience with PIC devices and would like to know whether PIC32 devices can run multiple processes at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  One way: you can write a scheduler.  A relatively simple way is to set up a timer, and when the timer ticks, you run an interrupt service routine which runs one of your tasks each time through.  This is called cooperative multi-tasking, as if any of the tasks overruns the timer tick, the other tasks have to wait for it to complete. If a task crashes, the whole system crashes.

Or you could get an operating system of some sort, for example [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/port_PIC32_MIPS_MK4.html) has a PIC32 port.  This will have scheduling (and inter process communication primitives, and a host of other O/S services) ready made for you.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by 'run multiple processes at the same time'.

Microchip PIC32 has only one core, so no, if you interpret 'run' as 'execute code instructions', it is not possible to run the multiple threads of execution that are required to run multiple processes at the same time.

That does not mean you cannot run an OS that supports multiple threads/processes and have them all operate in a useful and harmonious manner. Hardware and software interrupts can effectively change the set of running threads and the OS will run one of them on the one core until the next interrupt, same as on any other uC with a single-core architecture.

Comment: Does PIC32 even have an OS?

Comment: You seem to have hardware and OS's confused.  A PIC32 is a piece of hardware.  It can run any software that is compiled for it, including running an operating system.  There are many OS' available, see microchip's site: www.microchip.com/rtos